# API for private state

Tags: private-blockchain

assume that I have a private smart contract between peers A and B using quorum blockchain. Then, the variables of the smart contract will be placed in the private state.

My question is:

Can I make an API that enables to read some variables from the private state and returns a result?

Comment: Hi there. Just to be clear, without actually answering your query about APIs: a smart contract that exists on a private network is public to all users of that network. Unless users A and B are the _only_ users of that network, it won't be private to just them. There is no such thing as "private state".

Comment: Quorum is Ethereum plus an additional P2P layer that supports this kind of privacy.

Comment: Good point - what @RobHitchensB9lab said :-)